# JavaFx: Handling difference between caspian.css and modena.css

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8

In our application we allow Java7 and Java8. There is a difference between caspian.css and modena.css regarding SplitMenuButton.

*In caspian.css:*

```
/* The SplitMenuButton skin uses an inner Label part */
.split-menu-button .label {...
```

*In modena.css:*

```
.split-menu-button > .label {...}
```

We are using a different color for the label, and the problem is, I can't override it in such a way that it works with both Java7 and Java8.

What is the solution for this situation? 
Thx

Comment: `.split-menu-button > .label {...}` shall work for both, as ">" just means "direct child" which is true in both cases.

Comment: Under Java7 it doesn't work. If I leave the ">" out, than in Java8 the labels on the popup will be colored too, wich doesn't  happen under Java7, and shouldn't be too. If I use the ">" than in Java7 happens nothing, Java8 works fine.

Comment: I have tried this `.split-menu-button > .label {...}` with JavaFX2.2 using Java7 and with JavaFX8 using Java8 and in both cases the main button was colored, the popup remained untouched.